# React hook useState mutates a constant array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks to implement a form. The state of the form is being managed as an array of objects. A feature/bug of React appears to be that copies of arrays are processed/unified/mutated as a single array. That is, changes to one array become changes in all copies of the array.

I do not want to mutate the array as it creates an issue when attempting to use an array to initialize and reset the state. Once the initialization array becomes unified with the state array, the reset function will no longer work. I have made some attempts at preventing array unification without success. Below is the problem, some of my attempts to resolve the issue and a work around.

Lets say the state of the form is defined as:

```
const [field, setField] = useState(initialField);
```

Once this code executes, the value of array initialField is unified with the value of the array field.

Lets say we want to reset the form and use a function like this:

```
const reset = () =>{setField(initialField)}
```

This reset function will not work. Once the value of initialField is unified to the current value of field, setField will always contain the current value of field.

Lets say we replace initialField with:

```
initialField.map((e)=>{return e;})
```

The map method is immutable. It should create a separate array. However, replacing initialField with a map method of initialField does not change the result. useState still unifies the value of initalField with field.

Using the separator operator, {...intialField}, does not change the outcome. Neither does using intialField.concat(). Lets say we assign initalField to another array resetField. React will unify together all three arrays: field, initialField and resetField.

Lets say we hard code the array into the setState function. Assuming we have an array of N objects, it would look something like:

```
const [field, setField] = useState([{object 0}, {object 1} ... {object N}] );
```

The reset function is still:

```
const reset = () =>{setField(initialField)}
```

The reset function will work exactly once. Once the code is executed, React unifies initialField with field, so the reset function will no longer work. Lets say we replace initalField with a map method, a separator operator or a concat method. React will still unify the field array with initialField.

A work around this is to hard code the array into the setState and the reset functions as follows:

```
const [field, setField] = useState([{Object 0},{Object 1},...{Object N}]);

const reset = () =>{setField([{Object 0},{Object 1},...{Object N}])};
```

This is an ugly solution that complicates maintenance as the same changes have to be made twice.

Comment: `A feature/bug of React appears to be that copies of arrays are processed/unified/mutated as a single array. ` Not sure what makes you think this. Whatever you pass into `setField`, that's what the new state is. The only thing react does is a `===` between the old state and the new state, and this is only so it knows whether to skip rendering or not. If there's any processing/unification/mutation going on, it's likely in whatever calculations you're doing before you call `setField`.

Comment: This is difficult to follow.  I'm not sure what problem you're having or trying to solve. Can you show a runnable, [mcve] illustrating the problem(s) you're having? Arrays are objects, and objects aren't copied implicitly in JS. That's a good thing, because copying objects is expensive. That's a JS characteristic, not React, and furthermore, almost all languages I'm familiar with follow the same semantics so it's not an unusual design choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the issue is the reset function. When reset is clicked  in contained within the form

Comment: Thanks for the help. I attempted to recreate the issue and I think discovered what was causing the problem. I think it was a scope issue. I had declared the constant array outside the hook function. When this occurs, React unifies that array with the state. When the constant is declared inside the hook function, this issue no long presents. Thanks again.